# Saving a UIScrollview with buttons to NSuserdefaults

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uibutton, nsmutablearray

I have a scroll view full of buttons which are also in an NSMutableArray
how can i save the scrollview with the buttons so that they load in view did load.
I have a function that loads the buttons and places them into the scroll view and i have a function that removes the buttons. So it's the end state of the scrollview and its buttons needing to be saved.
If I can just save the array thats ok because I have a createButton function which takes in an NSString and creates a button in the scrollview and adds the object to the array so i suppose i could have 2 arrays but that hasn't worked and I'm fairly new so I think there is probably some really nice way to do this.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using NSUserDefaults, this is how you would do it.  This is how you would save just one array:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:yourArray forKey:@"SavedArray"];
```

And then load it:

```
yourArray = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"SavedArray"];
```

Or you could save button locations and button titles separately:

To save...

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:titlesArray forKey:@"Titles"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:locationsArray forKey:@"Locations"];
```

And to load...

```
titlesArray = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"Titles"]; 
locationsArray = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"Locations"];
```

NSUserDefaults are actually very cool how simple they are.  I hope this has helped.